# read outer file from a jar using getResourceAsStream(filename)

Tags: java, properties

I am using [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String filename)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to read a properties file in the same directory where my jar file is.

I have the same `configuration.properties` file in my jar too, so the method reads the inner properties file and not the outer one.

The method I'm using to read the file is :

```
public static Properties readProperties(String filename) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(filename); //only filename, not the full path of file
    props.load(stream);
    stream.close();
    return props;
}
```

and my Project structure is :

[image: Project structure]

Now, how do I read the outer properties file by overriding the inner-one by using `getResourceAsStream(filename)`???